# Where is the place where actual size of desktop icons is stored?

Tags: icons, customization, system

As one can resize the icons on *desktop* (not within nautilus) through righ-click menu: "Resize icon..", so where is the size stored for that certain file.

Comment: Have you looked at `/usr/share/pixmaps` ?

Comment: I meant those preview icons for my custom photo files or documents. IMHO they cannot be stored in /usr since you need extended privileges for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

File attributes for icons are stored in binary files inside `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/`.

To read an attribute for a file you need to use the `gvfs-info` command supplied by the `gcfs-bin` package.

To read the complete metadata stored from a file/folder on the `gvfs` use `gvfs-info -a "metadata::*" <path_to_file/folder>`, ie

> gvfs-info -a "metadata::*" /home/bruno/Desktop/Screenshot\ at\ 2011-12-14\ 21:29:29.png

```
attributes:
  metadata::icon-scale: 2.6875
  metadata::nautilus-icon-position-timestamp: 1323894580
  metadata::screen: 
  metadata::nautilus-icon-position: 77,15
```

To set an attribute inside the `gvfs` you use the command `gvfs-set-attribute` which is also part of `gvfs-bin` as this `gvfs-set-attribute <path_to_some_file/folder> metadata::some-key "some_value"`

If you want to change the scale of an icon in gnome you need to change the *icon-scale* attribute so for the file shown before if I wanted to reset the scale to **1** would do that as this

`gvfs-set-attribute /home/bruno/Desktop/Screenshot\ at\ 2011-12-14\ 21:29:29.png metadata::icon-scale "1"`

Unfortunately I could only see the changes after I logged off and back in on, `unity --replace &` did not do the trick. I am not sure if you can force Gnome to reload the data from the `gvfs` binaries.

Comment: I think you got my question wrong. On desktop icons there is a right-click menu "Resize icon...". If you click on that you get blue corners which you can drag and drop to a certain size, There are definitely more than 7 discrete levels. So where is that icon size parameter stored for that certain file on the desktop?

Comment: Sorry really imagined you wanted to change all the icons at the same time, will delete this and change it when I get the answer right.

Comment: Updated answer to fit your question.

Comment: Great even the thumbnail path is shown!

Comment: To reload the metadata, quit nautilus using `nautilus --quit` and then restart it using `nautilus -n`. Its important to run the last command using your desktop shell's "Run Command" because it will block your console and die when you quit the console.

Answer (score 0):

The icons doesnt really have a size, they are all SVG which are infinite on size.

The Size which nautilus use to display it inside itself its stored on the Nautilus hidden folder on your $HOME
(in .config/nautilus, but this may differ on newer versions)

Comment: The `.config/nautilus/desktop-metadata` file contains only metadata for "special icons" on the desktop, such as your trash.